# Problem Making Fonts Bigger in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to make my fonts bigger in my filter bar of an app that shows two checkboxes and a title with a button next to it.  That is, I don't have the option of adding a style to the page, I need to do it just with bootstrap 4 classes.  The section of code that I can add classes to is pasted below.

```
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-3">
                <div className="checkbox-bigger">
                    <div className="form-check-inline">
                        <label className="form-check-label">
                            <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    className="form-check-input"
                                    checked="false"
                            />
                            Saturday
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-3">
                <div className="checkbox-bigger">
                    <div>
                        <div className="form-check-inline">
                            <label className="form-check-label">
                                <input
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        className="form-check-input"
                                        checked="true"
                                />
                                Sunday
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" className="" value="xxx" />
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 p-3">
              <span className="font-italic">
                "20 of 30 shown" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </span>
                <span>
                <input type="image" src="https://unsplash.it/15/15" alt="refresh" />
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried adding to the "row" form-control-lg but that's not helped. I'm not good with Bootstrap and am not sure where to even look.

I've created a codesandbox version that shows my code plus code around it to give context to what larger should mean.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-https-xr3eh

Thanks for any help or pointers

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help. Using Bootstrap classes to increase the font size can be done in various ways.

Method 1: Using Display Classes

```
<h1 class="display-1">Display 1</h1>
<h1 class="display-2">Display 2</h1>
<h1 class="display-3">Display 3</h1>
<h1 class="display-4">Display 4</h1>
```

Note: These headers are not responsive.

Method 2: Using lead

```
<p class="lead">
  Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus.
</p>
```

Method 3: Using Responsive Font Sizes. This will be really interesting in your case

https://github.com/twbs/rfs/tree/v8.0.4

But as always Use h1 to h6 for different sizes.

Finally you can change the root element Normalfont size in your "application stylesheet" 
You can override something like below in your main stylesheet.

```
h3 {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

Hope this will give you some idea to solve your problem. Thanks